# JAVA Concurrency - waiting for process to complete

Tags: java

I am fairly new to JAVA and especially concurrency, so probably/hopefully this is fairly straight forward problem.

Basically from my main thread I have this:

```
public void playerTurn(Move move)
{

  // Wait until able to move
  while( !gameRoom.game.getCurrentPlayer().getAllowMove() )
  {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(200);
      trace("waiting for player to be available");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  gameRoom.getGame().handle(move);
}
```

gameRoom.getGame() is on its own thread.
gameRoom.getGame().handle() is synchronized
gameRoom.game.getCurrentPlayer() is on a varible of gameRoom.getGame(), it is in the same thread

allowMoves is set to false as soon as handle(move) is called, and back to true once it has finished processing the move.

I call playerTurn() multiple times. I actually call it from a SmartFoxServer extension, as and when it receives a request, often in quick succession.

My problem is, most times it works. However SOMETIMES it is issuing multiple handle(move) calls even though allowMoves should be false. Its not waiting for it to be true again. I thought its possible that the game thread didn't have a chance to set allowMoves before another handle(move) was called. I added volatile to allowMoves, and ensured the functions on the game thread were set to synchronized. But the problem is still happening.

These are in my Game class:

```
synchronized public void handle(Object msg)
{
  lastMessage = msg;
  notify();
} 

synchronized public Move move() throws InterruptedException
{
  while (true)
  {
   allowMoves = true;
   System.out.print(" waiting for move()...");
   wait();
   allowMoves = false;
   if (lastMessage instanceof Move)
   {
    System.out.print(" process move()...");
    Move m = (Move) lastMessage;
    return m;
   }
  }
}

public volatile boolean allowMoves;
synchronized public boolean getAllowMoves()
{
  return allowMoves;
}
```

As I said, I am new to this and probably a little ahead of myself (as per usual, but its kinda my style to jump into the deep end, great for a quick learning curve anyway).

Cheers for your help.

Comment: You don't need `synchronized ` for `getAllowMoves` volatile ensures visibility when you change the value

Comment: Thanks, but is that a cause to the problem I am having?

Comment: Also when I call handle(move), you'll see that interrupts my game class, which in turn sets allowMoves = false. I thought maybe the interrupt was delayed somehow, so allowMoves would still be true on the next call of playerTurn(). However I tried this; just before I call handle(move), I forcfully set allowMove = false from the main thread. The problem still remains. Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but what if you will use [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of `synchronized` and `volatile`? It says that it is `lock-free and thread-safe`.

Comment: I am trying this. The problem however remains. Perhaps there is a deeper logic problem in my game. Although I still believe it is linked to threading, as the problem is only happening SOMETIMES. According to my traces, its as if playerTurn(Move move) is being called in parallel somehow, my trace function reports it is within the same millisecond. I didn't even know this is possible.

Comment: yeah, seems like you run in race conditions somewhere. are you sure, that allowMoves variable is single instance belonging to only one thread? i.e. no other threads are duplicating the instance while updating it? is your code in public repo for us to look at?

Comment: I think Smart Fox Server is to blame. Gave acceptance to you as you helped, and have a lower reputation than others who answered equally well.

Comment: I have now iterated and reposted my qustion here: http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=15281

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you are using  `synchronized` method on two different objects.

```
 gameRoom.game.getCurrentPlayer().getAllowMove()<-- This is synchronized on 
                                                    CurrentPlayer instance.
 gameRoom.getGame().handle(move)<-- This is synchronized on `gameRoom.getGame()`
```

This is your issue. You don't need `synchronized` keyword for `getAllowMoves` since field is `volatile` as `volatile` guarantees  visibility semantics.

```
public boolean getAllowMoves() {
    return allowMoves;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how setting both to synchronized would cause the problem.. I am now simply directly using/setting allowMoves, and have removed the wrapper get/set functions. The problem remains.

Comment: I'll consider that, but its a fairly large project. I'll try to condense it down to just the problematic area, but its a fairly big job. I am now using AtomicBoolean, and have added more trace statements. I am perhaps more confused as to why I am having problems than when I first posted.

Comment: I concluded that my problem was regarding Smart Fox Server events and how it queues, calls request functions. Basically it doesn't handle having an independent game thread (or I haven't set it up right). I have the accepted answer to someone else as he made me aware of the Atomic classes, which seems neater/better than synchronized and volatile. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

there is the primitive, dedicated for resource management - [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

you need to

- create semaphore with permits set to 1
- use acquire when looking for a move
- use release after move is complete

so you will never face that 2 concurrent invocations of handle method appear.